# Issue in Linking Firebase to my android app

Tags: android

I am new to firebase and I followed the below link procedures to establish connection between firebase and myapp for my learning purpose.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#5
My authentication fails and enters into else statement and fails.
I cross checked the steps to be followed and i dot think i missed anything.
Please let me know where i am going wrong
[image: firebase config][image][image: program stops in]

Answer (score 3):

Please put **SHA certificate fingerprint** in your firebase account.

To get this follow these steps :

1.Open your project in Android Studio 
2.Click on **Gradle** Menu (From Right Side Panel )
3.Expand Your **Project** -> **Tasks** -> Double click on **siginingReports**
4.You will see **SHA-1** and **MD5** fingerprint in your run tab